# What are best practices for visualizing/selecting visualizations for continuous data?

Tags: data-visualization, references, continuous-data

There appear to be a large number of rules of thumb for histogram bin size and kernel selection for density plots. Are histograms and/or density plots really the best visualization for a single continuous variable? Are there other desirable options? Are there any settled best practices for visualizing continuous data that has no known distribution? Is there a good citable comprehensive reference source in the methods available and their advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Q-Q plots can be quite useful, but they take some time to learn to 'read' them well. KDE's are not the only choice for density plots (e.g. there's log-spline density estimation).

Comment: Depends on the sample size too. For really small samples, a dotplot is really probably the best, because densities, bin frequencies, quantiles (or hinges), etc. are just not knowable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for a citable reference, I would go for one of William Cleveland's book [Visualizing Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0963488406), also see his [author page](https://www.amazon.com/William-S.-Cleveland/e/B000AP9IPS/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1). See also this earlier questions:  https://www.amazon.com/William-S.-Cleveland/e/B000AP9IPS/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1 and [What's a good book or reference for data visualization?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261752/whats-a-good-book-or-reference-for-data-visualization).