# Good references on communicating the results of a statistical analysis to laypeople or non-expert stakeholders?

Tags: references, reporting, communication

I was wondering if there were some good references on communicating the results of data/statistical analysis to stakeholders or laypeople.

I'm not looking necessarily for [references related to data visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261752/whats-a-good-book-or-reference-for-data-visualization), even if it may be useful.

In fact, I'd be particularly interested by something relative to the use of *language* when presenting statistical results, in particular regarding the balance between expressing correctly an interesting statement, while making it accessible to laypeople.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I picked up lots of useful tips from The Art of Statistics by [David Spiegelhalter](https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Edavid/). I think he does an exceptional job of communicating some very abstract concepts without flattening the nuance in the process

Comment: Thanks! Following the link you give, I stumbled upon another website David Spiegelhalter contributed to (https://understandinguncertainty.org, now archived), and it looks like it offers some interesting content relative to my initial question (e.g. https://understandinguncertainty.org/exploring-language-chance-sensitive-context)